# Receive touch events after settings StackLayout.TranslateX property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentView with a StackLayout with multiple children sized to the full width of the screen. In other words, if the screen width is 320 and I have five children, the inner StackLayout is resized to 1600.

In this ContentView, I have Next and Previous buttons that when clicked, animate the inner StackLayout's TranslateX property. Basically, I'm creating a carousel by translating the StackLayout within the ContentView. I chose this route because I was having layout issues using a ScrollView and a custom renderer when I would modify that layout of the view (by hiding labels, etc.)

However, I've hit a snag. Content that appears after I set the TranslateX property doesn't receive any tap events. I believe I might have to reset some tappable area, but I'm not even sure where to begin with that. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same question in Xamarin's Forums, and someone there answered. For anyone looking, the answer is here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/142914/#Comment_142914

If that link stops working at some point in the future for some reason, the relevant answer is:

> Hit testing is done based on the actual frame of the control determined by layout, but translation happens after layout. Therefore hit testing does not take translation into account. If you want a view to be touchable then you should update its layout directly rather than using translation.